# Why does the function name inside a named function in JavaScript no longer refer to the function itself?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, name-binding

Consider the following named function:

```
function f() {
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

If you call this function normally it would result in a stack overflow as expected. Not very interesting. So let's do some magic:

```
var g = f, f = alert;
```

Now if you call `f` it will simply `alert` the first argument. However if you call `g` it will still `alert` the first argument. What's happening? Shouldn't calling `g` result in a stack overflow?

What I understand is that inside the function `f` (now `g`) the variable `f` is no longer bound to `f`. It becomes a free variable. Hence inside `f` the variable `f` now points to `alert`.

Why does this happen? I would expect the function name inside a named function to always refer to the function itself. I'm not complaining. It's actually pretty cool. I'm just curious.

Comment: When I run `var g = f, f = alert; g()` it throws a `TypeError` (undefined is not a function) as I expected (because `g` is assigned the value of `f` while `f` is undefined). How are you guys ending up with `g` as `alert`? Or is that second block supposed to be run in the same context as the first?

Comment: That's not what the OP is doing, he's doing: `var f = function () {...}, g = f, f = alert; g();`

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought they were two separate examples. You're right then, no recursion because `f` is reassigned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
var g = f
```

This is effectively the same as:

```
var g = function () {
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

However, since you reassigned `f` it no longer points to the original function, it now points to `alert`. Looks like it's working as designed.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers, it's as designed. Basically, apart from hoisting, the declaration is doing this:

```
var f = function () {
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

That is to say, the value of `f` is not resolved at the declaration but rather during the function call. Which is why you're seeing what you're seeing.

But there is a way to force it to behave the way you want: use a [named function expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129504/why-are-anonymous-function-expressions-and-named-function-expressions-initialize). A named function expression looks like a declaration but is not due to the function being declared as an expression.

For example, in the following:

```
var ff = function f () {
    return f.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

The value of `f` is bound at the declaration and will be immune to reassignment. In a named function expression, the function name is only defined inside the expression and therefore behaves more like a closure rather than a variable.